# deployed react app to azure web service app current node version 14 but but not deploying try many times using visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

showing Your app is targeting a runtime that is deprecated. Update your app to continue to receive bug and security fixes. this message show on azure web service why not deployed . it's run locally find.

deployed react app to azure web service app current node version  14 but  but not deploying try many times using visual studio code

past deployed many time it's working fine . but some day ago not able to deployed try many times using visual  studio code but not  able to deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the Node.js version specified in your deployment env
Go to the Azure Portal.
Navigate to your Web App.
In the left menu, under Settings, click on Configuration.
Look for an entry named WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION. Ensure it is set to the Node.js version you are using in your app (version 14 in your case).

Let me know if this works.